# How to get child record value from parent in AJAX toolkit?

Tags: apex, javascript, button, ajax-toolkit

I have onclick javascript

code:

```
var a = sforce.connection.query("select Name,Net_Price__c,(select Name,Net_Price__c,Price_HT__c from Services__r) from Rfleet_Car_Set__c where id ='{!Rfleet_Car_Set__c.Id}'" );
records = a.getArray("records");
var netPrice = records[0].Net_Price__c ;
var price = records[0].Services__r.Price_HT__c;
```

here am able to get the Net_Price__c from carset.

I want to get the Price_HT__c value from Service

Carset is Parent and Service is child.

Please help me thanks in adavnce

Comment: Assuming you want the value from first service child record..... 
var price = records[0].Services__r[0].Price_HT__c;

Comment: I want all the carset related services .Price_HT__c values

Comment: When i try to do this am getting "unable to get property of Price_HT_c"  var price = records[0].Services__r[0].Price_HT__c; @Stygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the records returned by the inner/sub query, you need to use getArray again on the relationship name of the current record.

```
for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var carset = records[i]; // Assign current carset record
    var services = carset.Services__r.getArray('records'); // get related services records for current carset record
    for (var j = 0; j < services.length; j++) {
        var service = services[j];
        var price = service.Price_HT__c;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you:)In alert am getting Price_HT_c  value .But after that alert am getting this error "unable to get property of Price_HT_c of undefined or null refernce "@Vigneshwaran G

Comment: I guess you copy pasted my code, and i wrongly had i in inner for loops :(. Check updated answer.